# Best way to run multiple projects with one gulp task?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am trying to use one gulp.js file to manage multiple themes I am building.

```
// Optimize images
gulp.task('images', function () {

  // palo theme
  return gulp.src('palo/images/**/*')
    .pipe($.cache($.imagemin({
      progressive: true,
      interlaced: true
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/palo/images'))
    .pipe($.size({title: 'images'}));

  // alto theme
  return gulp.src('alto/images/**/*')
    .pipe($.cache($.imagemin({
      progressive: true,
      interlaced: true
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/alto/images'))
    .pipe($.size({title: 'images'}));

});
```

I am not sure if I can build an array of each theme and loop it, I tried it and with no success.

```
var themes = ['palo','alto']

gulp.task('images', function () {

  for (i = 0; i < themes.length; i++) { 
    return gulp.src(themes[i]+'/images/**/*')
      .pipe($.cache($.imagemin({
        progressive: true,
        interlaced: true
      })))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'+themes[i]+'/images'))
      .pipe($.size({title: 'images'}));
 }

});
```

I would rather loop each theme instead of building a new block to return for each theme.

Comment: Looks like the problem is that you are using `return` inside your `for`, so only the first item of the array will be processed.

Comment: Yeah I did not think of that lol so I could store the gulp block into a variable, then return that?

Comment: Forgive me but how would I do something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a stream array:

```
 var es = require('event-stream');

 ...


 gulp.task('images', function () {

    var themes = [
        {
            src: 'palo/images/**/*',
            dest: 'dist/palo/images'
        },
        {
            src: 'alto/images/**/*',
            dest: 'dist/alto/images'
        }
    ];

    var tasks = themes.map(function(theme) {
        return gulp.src(theme.src)
            .pipe($.cache($.imagemin({
                progressive: true,
                interlaced: true
            })))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(theme.dest))
            .pipe($.size({title: 'images'}));
    })

    return es.merge.apply(null, tasks)

});
```

Comment: I think you mean to put `theme.src` && `theme.dest` NOT `themes.src` lol I saw this initially and should have knew to make the change but I was just following what you advised because I thought maybe for some reason it was different in this case.

Comment: Yeah, sure... sorry! Updated it